# Some results given that $|G| = nm$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group such that $|G| = nm$. 
Suppose $x\in G$ has order $n$ and let $\sigma_x\in S_G$ be the permutation such  that $\sigma_x(g)=xg$ for every $g\in G$. Note that $\sigma_x$ is a product of $m$ disjoint n-cycles.

a) Show that if $n=2$ and $m$ is odd, show that there is a homomorphism $f : G \to S_{nm}$ such that $f(G) \not \subseteq A_{nm}$.

b) Show that if $n=2$ and $m$ is odd, conclude that $G$ has a subgroup of index $2$.

Answer (score 1):

The homomorphism $h$ is given by $x\to\sigma _x$, where $\sigma _xg=xg\,,\forall g\in G$. When $\mid x\mid=n$, since $\sigma _x$ is a product of $m$ disjoint $n$ cycles, $n=2$ and $m$ odd implies $\sigma_x\in S_{nm}$ is odd.

For the second part,  let $H\subset G$ be given by $H=h^{-1}(A_{nm})$.  Then it is easy to see that $[G:H]=2$.

Comment: @Custer Could you explain your answer to the first part more? Why is $h$ a homomorphism if we require that $|x| = 2$? Shouldn't we be able to map any element in $G$, not just those of order $2$?

Comment: Those are really two separate facts.  It's easy to check that $h(x+y)=h(x)+h(y)$.  So $h$ is a homomorphism.   We are additionally given that there is an element of order $n$.

Comment: $h$ is defined on all of $G$.

Comment: @Custer I think I see. There only needs to exist one such odd cycle for the image not to be a subset. And since we know that |x|=2 that is one such cycle. But also, could you explain part 2 a bit more? I am not seeing how it's "easy to see."

Comment: We know $[G:H]\gt1$ by $(a)$.  On the other hand $[G:H]\le2$ because $\frac GH$ maps injectively into $\frac{S_{nm}}{A_{nm}}$.